# Idle / Inactivity tracking with RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I needed to implement a way to track idle state / inactivity in a browser (Angular app), so I tried to create an observable that would trigger whenever there wasn't any user-interaction event, so the client can automatically log out:

```
import {filter, from, fromEvent, mergeAll, Observable, of, repeat, timeout} from 'rxjs';

const timeoutDelay = 1000 * 60 * 5; // 5 minutes
const events = ['keypress', 'click', 'wheel', 'mousemove', 'ontouchstart'];    
const $onInactive = from(events.map(e => fromEvent(document, e)))
  .pipe(
    mergeAll(),
    timeout({each: timeoutDelay, with: () => of(undefined as any)}),
    filter(a => !a),
    repeat()
);
```

And while I was able to make it work with the code above, I'm not sure if this is done correctly or efficiently for this specific task, so I just wanted to double-check here.

The client would be using the above code like this:

```
$onInvactive.subscribe(() => {
    // no user activity for 5 minutes

    // if currently logged in, then log out
});
```

The notification is supposed to arrive whenever inactivity happens, throughout the lifetime of the web client.

**SOLUTION**

Based on the accepted answer, below is a complete Angular v15 service for this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Observable,
  fromEvent, interval, merge,
  repeat, takeUntil, map,
} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InactivityService {

  readonly timeoutDelay = 1000 * 60 * 5; // 5 minutes

  readonly $onIdle: Observable<void>;

  constructor() {
    const events = ['keypress', 'click', 'wheel', 'mousemove', 'ontouchstart'];
    const $signal = merge(...events.map(eventName => fromEvent(document, eventName)));
    this.$onIdle = interval(this.timeoutDelay).pipe(takeUntil($signal), map(() => undefined), repeat());
  }

}
```

So any component or other service can easily track idle state:

```
constructor(private inactivity: InactivityService) {
    this.inactivity.$onIdle.subscribe(() => {
        // user is idle for 5 minutes;
        // it is emitted repeatedly
    });
}
```

Comment: You were originally correct that asking for more efficient implementations or opinion-based "correctness" questions are off topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's actually a very good question!
Your approach for tracking certain activity events is clever, but in the end it really depends on your definition of "inactivity". If your are happy with your current definition, then you can probably track a few more like scroll or resize.

Another "inactivity" definition could be "user is active as long as the tab is active". In modern browsers this can be tracked via the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API#browser_compatibility) aka listen for the `visibilitychange` event in your document. Using window focus and blur Events on the window object should also work as a workaround.

Now, coming to the implementation itself, I will suggest a simplified approach.

```
const browserInactive$ = (graceTime: number): Observable<Event> => {
    const activityIndicatorEvents = ['click', 'mousemove', 'mousedown', 'scroll', 'keypress'];
    return merge(...activityIndicatorEvents.map(eventName => fromEvent(document, eventName))).pipe(debounceTime(graceTime));
};
```

I haven't tested this myself, but the idea is quite simple. It follows your original implementation but we use `debounceTime` as a mechanism to wait for the graceTime to "expire" and a function as a convenient way to configure the behavior.

EDIT 1:
Got an idea to make it easy for your Angular components or services to consume the Observable

```
export const BROWSER_INACTIVE$ = new InjectionToken<Observable<Event>>('Browser inactivity detector', {
    factory: () => {
        const activityIndicatorEvents = ['click', 'mousemove', 'mousedown', 'scroll', 'keypress'];
        const graceTime = 1000 * 60 * 5; // 5 minutes
        return merge(...activityIndicatorEvents.map(eventName => fromEvent(document, eventName))).pipe(debounceTime(graceTime), share());
    }
});
```

Then it can be used like this:

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(
    @Inject(BROWSER_INACTIVE$) private readonly browserInactive$: Observable<Event>
  ) {}
}
```

EDIT 2: Based on OP feedback.
In that case, we can use a slighty different approach:

```
const browserInactive$ = (graceTime: number): Observable<any> => {
  const activityIndicatorEvents$ = merge(
      ...['click', 'mousemove', 'mousedown', 'scroll', 'keypress'].map(
          (eventName) => fromEvent(document, eventName)
      )
  );

  return interval(graceTime).pipe(
      takeUntil(activityIndicatorEvents$),
      repeat()
  );
};
```

The idea now is that we have a some sort of *timer* (an `interval` actually) that will emit every `gracePeriod` unless an **activityIndicator** event is detected. The problem is that `takeUntil` will complete the stream, so we need to use `repeat` to keep it alive :)

Comment: Thank you for detailed solution! I have tested the first one, and it only fires once, whereas in my solution it happens repeatedly, after every 5 minutes if inactivity. I did state - `The notification is supposed to arrive whenever inactivity happens, throughout the lifetime of the web client`. I tried to inject `repeat()` into the pipeline, but that didn't do it :|

Comment: Can you update the answer for continuous events, please, as per my previous post?

Comment: That playground doesn't work, it emits events even when there is activity.

Comment: Oops, sorry... wrong link :(
Here's the one https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6hsmgf

Comment: That seems to work correctly, apart from the `wheel` event that you removed ;)

Comment: Typical Friday :D

Comment: Thanks for the updates! I have added my final solution into the question, based on your answer ;)